# Computational issue with Planck function

Tags: limits, computer-science, limits-without-lhopital, computational-mathematics

I have the following formula for a function in Fortran 90 used to find the spectral radiance at a given wavelength and temperature. I've expressed it as:

```
intensity = (2.0d0*h*nu**(3.0d0))/c**(2.0d0) * 1d0 / (EXP((h*nu)/(k*T))-1d0)
```

Where I take wavelength as an argument, which is then converted to nu. As my wavelengths tend to infinity, Fortran begins to say that the intensity is infinite, returning `Inf`. However, the Planck function converges to 0 as the wavelength tends to infinity. Why is this?

My theory is that perhaps, since nu = c/lambda, as lambda tends to infinity, a part of the function is divided by 0, so this tends it to infinity. However, there is also a -5 power law on wavelength as well, which is meant to overall keep the function converging at 0, but this doesn't seem to be the case by Fortran's computation. Why is this? What's going wrong? It's essentially saying zero times `Inf` is `Inf.`

For the record, I didn't think submitting blocks of my code was important here -- this is part of an exercise where this problem is meant to arise, so I know my code isn't malfunctioning.

Is this merely an issue with Fortran, or is there some other underlying mathematical reason for this?

Comment: Lots of floating point issues happen when you start basically computing 0/0 type things. Some libraries have a function expm1 that can help you out some here.

Comment: @Ian I see. Floating point issues can turn an intended result of $0$ into a perceived result of $\infty$?

Comment: The issue is basically that if the division gives infinity then multiplying it by a small number doesn't fix anything. This will begin to happen once $\frac{h\nu}{k_B T}$ passes through roughly $10^{-16}$, at which point the difference in the denominator will wind up being just zero in floating point arithmetic. This is what expm1 helps with; expm1(10**-20) gives a nonzero result (probably just the closest floating point number to $10^{-20}$) while exp(10**-20)-1 will definitely give zero in double precision.

Comment: @Ian I see. Why is $10^{-16}$ the magic number? So, that ends up being a division by zero rendering infinity, but why is this "more infinity" than the $-5$ power law on $\lambda$ is "more zero", for lack of better language?

Comment: Basically what happens in floating point arithmetic is that $a-b=0$ if $a=(1+r)b$ and $|r|$ is less than "machine epsilon", which in double precision floating point is $2^{-53}$. So you divide by exactly-zero and then multiply by small-but-not-zero.